# What is the difference between Doc and Comment in go/ast package?

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using the `go/ast` and `go/parser` package to do something, but i am puzzled about the difference between `Doc` and `Comment`.

Is the first line of comments a `Doc`, then others as `Comment`?
Here is a sample:

```
TypeSpec struct {
    Doc     *CommentGroup // associated documentation; or nil
    Name    *Ident        // type name
    Type    Expr          // *Ident, *ParenExpr, *SelectorExpr, *StarExpr, or any of the *XxxTypes
    Comment *CommentGroup // line comments; or nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`src/go/ast/ast.go#L70-L75`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f1878c0d4670a8ebde9579a3eebb589dfca26716/src/go/ast/ast.go#L70-L75):

```
// A CommentGroup represents a sequence of comments
// with no other tokens and no empty lines between.
```

Following [Godoc: documenting Go code](http://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code):

- `Doc` is one or several continuous lines of comments (`// ...`) *before* the [`TypeSpec`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/f1878c0d4670a8ebde9579a3eebb589dfca26716/src/go/ast/ast.go#L847-L853)

> write a regular comment directly preceding its declaration, with no intervening blank line

```
// A TypeSpec node represents a type declaration (TypeSpec production).
^^^^^^^^^^^^...
TypeSpec struct {
```

- `Comment` is a comment associate to the field itself, *starting on the same line*, but which can spread over multiple continuous lines (hence "`CommentGroup`")

  ```
  Name    *Ident        // type name
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
                        // the comment associated to Name
                        // could go on over several lines
  ```

Comment: Field can also have a `Doc`? And Type have only `Doc`, no `Comment`?

Comment: Field can have *comments* starting on the same line. while a Type can have a *doc* (lines of comments *before* the type)